# How looks a wheel browsing 299000km in 1 second from its own frame?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, reference-frames, time-dilation, observers

Imagine a wheel with a 299km perimeter turning at 1000 round per second going 299000km (the speed of the wheel is 299000km/s relative to the starting frame).

How does it look in the frame of a pilot at the center of the wheel (seeing the wheel turning)?

How (in the frame of the pilot) the wheel can go the same 299'000km in a laps of time smaller (time dilation) with also 1000 round/s?

Comment: What do you mean by "browsing"? That word doesn't make any sense in this context.

Comment: False translation of the french "parcourir"

Answer (score -1):

> How does it look in the frame of a pilot at the center of the wheel
>   (seeing the wheel turning)?

It looks like a spinning wheel.

> How (in the frame of the pilot) the wheel can browse the same
>   299'000km in a laps of time smaller (time dilation) with also 1000
>   round/s?

I'm not sure what you mean but speed is what causes Special Relativity. It does not change the speed.

If you're asking what would happen if the outer edge was travelling faster than the speed of light, then the answer is it would never get up to that speed; the shear forces would tear the wheel apart before then.

Comment: From the point of view of the pilot: how 1000 round in less than a second can do 299000km with a 299km perimeter?